# ActiveAdmin ::Show 4 textbox in active admin using has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I have one poll table having with question filed and each question have 4 answer which is has_many relation ship with answer table

```
   class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_many :answer
    end
```

My answer model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :poll,  :class_name => "Poll", :foreign_key => "question_id"
end
```

My active admin form is

```
   form :html => {:validate => true} do |f|
    f.inputs "Polls" do
      f.input :question
      f.has_many :answer, :sortable => :priority do |ff|
        ff.input :question[]
      end 

      f.input :status,as:  'hidden',:input_html => { :value => f.object.status.present? ?  f.object.status : 'Unpublished' }
      f.input :position,as:  'hidden',:input_html => { :value =>  Poll.count().to_i + 1}
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

I want to show only 4 answer textbox into my form, how can i do that

Comment: what is it showing with the above?

Comment: `has_many :answers` pay attention to the pluralization. If you do `poll.answer ` and get an array thats a real WTF moment.

Comment: I want to show 4 question textbox into my form , I want to edit my code below

     f.has_many :answer, :sortable => :priority do |ff|
        ff.input :question[]
      end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Polls Controller-

```
def new
  @poll = Poll.new
  4.times do
    @poll.answers.build
  end
end
```